# How to show menu on the bottom of a icon in grid cell in extjs4

Tags: extjs

On my grid, I have put a icon on a cell and on the click event I am showing a menu option. the menu displays by event.getXY() position but I want to show the menu start from the bottom of the icon or the specific cell like:

Or like standard plugin opens the calendar just from the bottom of cell.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your code on jsfiddle.

Comment: what is jsfiddle.I am new here.Please suggest

Comment: jsfiddle.net you can put your HTML, JS and CSS code here so that we can easily review it and suggest solutions.

Comment: shubhanshu..plz join me on fb: http://www.facebook.com/ankit.srivastav.98

Answer (score 1):

```
itemcontextmenu: function (grid, rec, item, index, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var rect = event.target.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect(); // try to play with or without 'parentElement'
    var x = rect.left;
    var y = rect.top + rect.height;
    myMenu.showAt(x, y);
}
```

Tested on Chrome, IE9